# 2012 html emails - tables, divs and @media

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-email

What are current trends with html email?

Looking into repsonsive design html email I came across [this](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/mobile/responsive/) article on campaignmonitor.

It seems to mix css @media queries and other css in style blocks rather than inline styles,  with old school table layouts.

Surely, if an email client is capable of processing css it knows what to do with a div? Or is the table just as a fallback for those that still can't? And the media queries and block css extra sweetness for those that do?

I realise that email clients don't change as rapidly as web browsers but are tables still the best way forward?

I'm sure this question has been asked loads of times before, but I'm looking for modern trends.

Perhaps this should be another question, but I also notice that the article mixes element.class and element[class="classname"] declarations - the last of which I've only ever used with input[type="value"] before. Why the square brackets for classes?

Comment: Tables on itself is a save fallback to if indeed divs are not working. Where tables are standard elementes, that respond in every browser different, divs can change (think about margin / padding - etc) chosing for a table is more a security, i think, although dont quote me on this.  About your square brackets question, that depends. It can be used as a validation, however, i dont see how its changed here. Further on, its a legal way of specifying something, and something in particular, meaning the css applies only to that element specificly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently my company was changing their emails layout. First we decided to test the compatibility of different email clients with the newest html/css standards. However, during the coding process we encountered many problems with proper rendering which forced us to turn back to `table`-based layout.

We also used `@media-queries` and more sophisticated styling for clients able to understand them, but unfortunately `tables` are still the way to go if you want to support popular mail clients. It's a pity that so many business clients use old Outlook or similar.

After the work was done, we were testing our layouts with [Campaign Monitor Tester](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/testing/) but it wasn't enough so we had to test many clients manually.

Summing up: If I was to code an email layout now, I'd go with tables and inline styles.

Edit: Brackets-notation is correct, but I don't see the point. Moreover in this example it will only match elements with exactly one class named `classname`. It won't match `<p class="classname othername">`. If there's no other arguments for using it here, I'd go with standard dot notation (`.classname`).

Comment: The bracketing can be used to avoid Yahoo Mail's preference for pulling in the responsive version of an email's styles instead of the inline table styling.

Comment: I suppose tables and backward compatibility it is then. I guess campaign monitor know a thing or two about html emails.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that you need to inline all your css for maximum compatibility. Campaignmonitor has a tool that auto inlines it for you, so keep that in mind when reading their suggestions.

Reason css needs to be inlined is because of web-based clients like gmail and (i think also) yahoo stripping out the style declarations (as well as everything outside the body tags) to ensure it doesn't mess up with their webpage. Media queries can't be inlined, so even though it is a current trend to make responsive emails, note they won't work in gmail.

Still work in tables because there are inconsistencies with different email clients, particularly how they handle different css properties. One of the major reasons emails are 'stuck in the past' is because of Outlook which uses the MS Word render engine. Outlook is still the most popular email client particularly with B2B.

Hope that info helps!